# GPars - How do I know if actor is busy?

Tags: java, multithreading, actor, gpars

I'm trying to use GPars in Java to handle messages of a few types. 
There is one actor for each message type.

But message processing takes a lot of time, while messages keep coming. I need to ignore upcoming messages (just throw them away) while the actor is busy.

How do I know if an GPars actor is busy? I know about `Actor.isActive()` method, but I'm not too sure that it is the thing (the JavaDoc is pretty ambiguous and unclear) and I couldn't find any useful info ether.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to determine this, I'm afraid. You'd have to implement a busy-controlling algorithm yourself, perhaps based on CountdownLatches.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this can be problematic, as an actor can only process one message at a time, whatever solution you have to do this, will have limitations. For instance you can have an actor within an actor, a supervisor and a worker.

The worker actor is the one which actually does the work. What happens is work is sent to the supervisor. The supervisor has a boolean variable such as isBusy, which is initially false. When work is received the supervisor sets the variable to true, and passes the work on to the worker. When the work is finished the worker sends the result back to the supervisor and the supervisor sets the isBusy to false and returns the result.

If another message comes in whilst the isBusy is false the supervisor can just send a message back such as an isBusy message, or do nothing which is what you say you want.

Note that if the worker crashes, or restarts, the isBusy will still be true. You will need to think about this solution, if it will meet your needs. There maybe a mailbox which would be better for this I don't know.

Whatever you do, you should try your best to avoid creating situations where you could leave your actor system in a bad state, best of luck.